# Watermarking a .png, .gif or .jpg with a .png, .gif or .jpg

Tags: php, transparency, gd, watermark

I'm trying to write a function that will watermark any image (.png, .jpg or .gif) with another image that might also be one of those formats. I wish both of the images to retain transparency. I do not care about gif animation. Unfortunately, the watermark gets transparent where it's not supposed to, and doesn't entirely get transparent where it is. I used some random images available to me to test this script, and my result looks like this:

[image]

While the watermark images look like this:

[image]

[image]

Here's my code:

```
  function watermark_get_left()
  {
    return NCFG_TEMPLATE_DIR . 'images/watermark_left.png';
  }

  function watermark_get_right()
  {
    return NCFG_TEMPLATE_DIR . 'images/watermark_right.png';
  }

  function create_img($path, $type)
  {
    switch($type)
    {
      case NCFG_IMAGE_JPG:
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
        return $img;
      case NCFG_IMAGE_GIF:
        $img = imagecreatefromgif($path);
        return $img;
      case NCFG_IMAGE_PNG:
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($path);
        imagealphablending($img, false);
        imagesavealpha($img, true);
        return $img;
      default:
        return FALSE;
    }
  }

  function img_transparency($new_img, $img, $type)
  {
    if($type == NCFG_IMAGE_GIF)
    {
      $transparent_index = imagecolortransparent($img);

      if($transparent_index != -1)
      {
        $transparent_color = imagecolorsforindex($img, $transparent_index);
        $transparent_new = imagecolorallocate($new_img, $transparent_color['red'], $transparent_color['green'], $transparent_color['blue']);
        $transparent_new_index = imagecolortransparent($new_img, $transparent_new);
        imagefill($new_img, 0, 0, $transparent_new_index);
      }
    }else if($type == NCFG_IMAGE_PNG){
      imagecolortransparent($new_img, imagecolorallocatealpha($new_img, 0, 0, 0, 127));
      imagealphablending($new_img, false);
      imagesavealpha($new_img, true);
    }
  }

  function image_watermark($path, $new_path, &$w_height)
  {
    $type = get_image_type($path);
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($path);

    if(!($img = create_img($path, $type)))
    {
      return FALSE;
    }

    $l_path = watermark_get_left();
    $r_path = watermark_get_right();

    if($l_exists = file_exists($l_path))
    {
      $l_type = get_image_type($l_path);
      list($l_width, $l_height) = getimagesize($l_path);

      if(!($l_img = create_img($l_path, $l_type)))
      {
        return FALSE;
      }
    }

    if($r_exists = file_exists($r_path))
    {
      $r_type = get_image_type($r_path);
      list($r_width, $r_height) = getimagesize($r_path);

      if(!($r_img = create_img($r_path, $r_type)))
      {
        return FALSE;
      }
    }

    $w_height = max(($r_exists ? $r_height : 0), ($l_exists ? $l_height : 0));

    echo("w_height: $w_height<br/>");

    $new_width = $width;
    $new_height = $height + $w_height;

    $new_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

    $bg_color = imagecolorallocate($new_img, 255,255,255);
    imagefilledrectangle($new_img, 0, $height, $new_width - 1, $new_height - 1, $bg_color);

    img_transparency($new_img, $img, $type);
    imagecopy($new_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);

    if($l_exists)
    {
      imagecopy($new_img, $l_img, 0, $height, 0, 0, $l_width, $l_height);
    }

    if($r_exists)
    {
      imagecopy($new_img, $r_img, $new_width - $r_width, $height, 0, 0, $r_width, $r_height);
    }

    switch($type)
    {
      case NCFG_IMAGE_JPG:
        imagejpeg($new_img, $new_path);
        break;
      case NCFG_IMAGE_GIF:
        imagegif($new_img, $new_path);
        break;
      case NCFG_IMAGE_PNG:
        imagepng($new_img, $new_path, 9);
        break;
    }

    imagedestroy($new_img);
    imagedestroy($img);

    return TRUE;
  }
```

I've also tried imagecopymerge, to no avail. I'd appreciate any help on this.

Edit: My images were displayed here, unlike what I expected. The watermarked image looks correct on the white background, but it does not on any other background.

Comment: I wish both of the images to retain transparency. I do not care about transparency.

Comment: As far as I know, watermarks are supposed to be semi-transparent. Thus you cannot use a jpg as watermark since it has not transparency. And this is REALLY confusing: "I wish both of the images to retain transparency. I do not care about transparency." Do you want it or not?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write "I do not care about gif animation"... I've been at it for too long.

Comment: I am embedding my watermarks at the bottom, after extending the image's height.

Comment: The brush works really good for copying a transparent image on another image, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetbrush.php - in my experience imagecopy etc. do very often not work as one might expect.

Comment: Thanks Niko, this helps a lot! :) It finally works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ImageMagick CLI for this. Here's a one liner:

```
composite -dissolve 50% -geometry +20+10 -gravity SouthWest watermark.png input.png output.png
```

This will put `watermark.png` on top of `input.png` with an opacity of `50%` in the `SouthWest` corner with an offset of `+20, +10` pixels. You can tweak it to your liking and use it in PHP with `shell_exec`:

```
shell_exec('composite ...');
```

Reference: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php

Sample image:

[image]

***Edit:***
If you also want to extend the original image's height (by 20 pixels, for example), you need to do this first:

```
convert original.png -bordercolor transparent -border 0x20 -background transparent -gravity NorthWest -extent +0+20 input.png
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have ImageMagick installed on my server. I also do not have access to install it.